# TypeError: this.props.updateCommentText is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been following a tutorial for react. Everything went fine but now I get an error I cannot seem to solve. Help is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to edit the text variable for a Comment however when I try to call the function it gives the following error.

error: TypeError:
`this.props.updateCommentText is not a function`

Board class:

```
class Board extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        comments: [
          "Hello1",
          "Hello2",
          "Hello3",
        ],
    };
  }
  getInitialState() {
    return {comments: [
      "Hello1",
      "Hello2",
      "Hello3",
    ]}
  }

  removeComment(i){
    var arr = this.state.comments;
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({comments: arr})
  }

  updateComment(i, newText){
    var arr = this.state.comments;
    arr[i] = newText;

  }

  eachComment(text, i){
    return(
      <Comment key={i} index={i} updateCommentText={this.updateComment.bind(this)} deleteFromBoard={this.removeComment}>
        {text}
      </Comment>);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="board">
        {this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment.bind(this))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment class:

```
    class Comment extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editing : false,
      text : "",
    };
  }

  getInitialState() {
    return {editing: false}
  }
  edit() {
    this.setState({editing: true});
  }

  remove() {
    console.log('delete');
    this.props.deleteFromBoard(this.props.index)
  }

  save() {
    var text = this.refs.newText.value;
    this.props.updateCommentText(this.props.index, text);
    this.setState({editing: false});
  }

  renderNormal(){
    return(
      <div className="commentContainer">
        <div className="commentText">{this.props.children}</div>
        <button onClick={this.edit.bind(this)} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
        <button onClick={this.remove} className="button-primary">Remove</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderForm(){
    return(
      <div className="commentContainer">
        <textarea ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
        <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)} className="button-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render(){
      if(this.state.editing){
        return this.renderForm();
      }else{
        return this.renderNormal();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a bind? `deleteFromBoard={this.removeComment.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: In your `Board` Component you are declaring getInitialState and Constructor at the same time, they are **practically the same thing**. Contructor is the new sintax of react, getInitialState is **depracated**. 
Second, avoid the use of bind inline, declare in your constructor. So in your Board Class would be better if ypu rewrite your constructor like this:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        comments: [
          "Hello1",
          "Hello2",
          "Hello3",
        ],
    };
    this.updateComment = this.updateComment.bind(this);
    this.removeComment=this.removeComment.bind(this);
  }
```

And the last, and probaly your error, you need to pass the context to your props, inside Board component.

```
  <Comment key={i} index={i} updateCommentText={this.updateComment(i, text)} deleteFromBoard={this.removeComment(i)}>
        {text}
      </Comment>);
```

Comment: Hm ... do you mean `this.updateComment.bind(this, i, text)`. I'm asking because as it is written in your example the function is directly called.

Comment: Setting the binds in constructors was great tip! However I also needed to bind as Krasimir did in his commend for it to work! Also thanks for explaining the depracated method.

Comment: @YuriRamos I meant that when you are giving a function as a prop value that function shouldn't be called there. You should pass the function, maybe partially executed but this.updateComment(i, text) looks like you are invoking the function at rendering time.

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed weird. I can't say why you are getting this error. It looks like everything is wired properly and I tried the code above. I was able to hit the save button without seeing this error. However, there are couple of things that should be changed:

- `removeComment` is missing a bind in `deleteFromBoard` prop
- `remove` in `Comment` also does not have a binding.
- Try to avoid using `bind` in `render` functions. This means that you are binding every time when a component is rendered. Do this in the constructor once.
- You don't have to pass the `index`. Just use `this.updateComment.bind(this, i)`. This will make `updateComment` partially executed. (in this case you have to use `bind` there).
- In `updateComment` you are mutating the state but you are not calling `setState`. There really should be `this.setState({ comments: arr })`. Without that you are not seeing the edits.